# JavaScript not loading into HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

I looked for a slider online and I got here (https://codepen.io/doodlemarks/pen/aFcly), so I copied the code into their respective html, css and js files (which contains more code), but the JS code ain't working. I linked it with a  tag, but still doesn't work. (The provided code is a fragment of the HTML file; The css and js code is copied into their files just as the page shows).

```
    <script language="JavaScript" src="js/slider.js"></script>

    <div class="galeria">
   <h1 class="titulo">Galería</h1>
        <div id="slider">
                <a class="control_next">></a>
                <a   class="control_prev"><</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>SLIDE 1</li>
                    <li>SLIDE 2</li>
                    <li>SLIDE 3</li>
                    <li>SLIDE 4</li>
                </ul>
         </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: ´Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined at slider.js:1´  looks like you need to import jQuery into your page

Answer (score 0):

The `src` is supposed to provide a path to your JS file. If you have a file structure like:

```
>index.html
>main.js
```

( both being on the same level )

the `src` should be `src="./main.js"`.

Comment: In the same folder where the html file is, there is a folder called "js" and inside it, it is located the slider.js file, so I think the route should be ok.

Comment: Yes, that should be fine then. Put a console log at the top of your JS file and see if that runs, if it doesn't, maybe try to change the `src` to `src="./js/slider.js` anyway.

Comment: I changed the src and still doesn't work. Does any part of the js code provided by the page need to be changed? (Like src="route" where route=my documents route or something like that). I also tried writing the content of the js file between de <script> tags and still didn't work